# Allow url redirect pop-ups in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

My app is having webview using WKWebView. Webview contains one link which prompt browser for pop-up for redirecting to new url.

My question is there any delegate method which invokes when pop-up will prompt?

I tried webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? but it didn't work.

Pop up looks like in firefox browser:
[image]

Comment: That is the delegate method you need to implement. Is ir being called?  If not, did you set the web view delegate correctly? What is the method used in the web page to do the popup?

Comment: @LouFranco - It's not being called. I have set delegate properly in viewDidLoad method. On web i don't know about which method has been used to create redirect pop-up for opening in new tab